# The Eclipse executable launcher is unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: exe

I am having trouble uploading this version of BIRT. I am getting this error. I am getting "The Eclipse executable launcher is unable to locate its companion shared library."

I saved it in a secured area within my windows so that I can download this version of BIRT.